# Time difference in hours javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called nowTime and it looks like this

```
Mon Feb 24 2014 11:57:53 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)
```

and another variable with another date like this

```
Mon Mar 24 2014 11:20:33 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)
```

and I apply the following equation to get the difference in hours

```
var hours = Math.abs(nowTime - notTime) / 36e5;
```

but hours is equal to 671.3777638888889

why is that?

Comment: @dystroy I think `Feb` stands for "February"

Comment: If you're doing your division **outside** of Math.abs, isn't it normal for such output to emerge?

Comment: Please show us a testable code, with the date parsing part. And tell us what you'd expect.

Comment: @Kippie The `abs` only changes the sign

Comment: It's correct. You fave February and March in two dates.

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly because there's 672 hours between 24th February and 24th of March